# flycheck errors on (require) statements in package: cannot load file

Tags: require, package-development

i maintain a multi-file package, and i'm having trouble with require statements in it, both for child files of the main parent file inside the package, and for requiring dependencies, which in my case are always installed via MELPA/package.el.

flycheck reports:
"Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, $pkgname"

for a long time i ignored this, and also other testers of the package have reported not seeing the issue. the problem with it is that it prevents flycheck from continuing properly and displaying all subsequent issues in the same file, so i miss problems in my code that flycheck normally helps me find.

wrapping it in `eval-when-compile` has no effect on this issue.

why cant flycheck find my installed/loaded dependencies? it seems the only things it won't baulk at are files that are officially part of emacs itself.

[i looked on stackexchange for similar issues with require, but didn't find one regarding packages.]

Comment: @d123q thanks very much, yes it does.